# Why is the first call to MySQL database very slow?

Tags: mysql, performance, debian, tomcat6

On my server (debian wheezy) I run a mysql database and a tomcat6 server. Just after the deployement of my application with tomcat, the first call to my mysql database is strangely slow. On the server we log the time of each method calling the database :

```
First launch    Second launch
5268 ms         0 ms
22 ms           8 ms
5296 ms         9 ms
23359 ms        96 ms
18 ms           7 ms
23379 ms        103 ms
19 ms           8 ms
273 ms          136 ms
161 ms          88 ms
327 ms          169 ms
1014 ms         484 ms
1796 ms         885 ms
18 ms           5 ms
24 ms           6 ms
48 ms           15 ms
52014 ms        1106 ms
127598 ms       1879 ms
179708 ms       3013 ms
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: slow tcp connections due to slow reverse DNS due to using user@host-type account names, forcing MySQL to do a reverse ip->name lookup? firewall doing its own lookups? all kinds of network-related stuff could be happening, but no way to tell.

Comment: Could you please read over this 'question' as at present, it would be IMPOSSIBLE to answer? There are just too many possible reasons here (from bad SQL querys, to bad network issues) :(

Comment: If it was bad SQL querys or network issues, wouldn't it be slow everytime, not just the first time after a tomcat deployment ?

Comment: Sara, if you are doing the queries directly (or close) after each other for timing measurement, you could hit MySQL's query cache. It is not unusual for a (bad) query itself being answered faster the second time.